# Add topojson on top of google map

Tags: json, google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3, topojson

I am following this example (http://bl.ocks.org/zross/10654766) and trying to replace the data which is counties in California to counties in the whole US.  The data I used to replace the one in example is https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json. I saved it as uscounty.json.

My problem is topojson file can not align properly with googlemap at a right position in spite of the features do show up. I guess it has something to do with the projection but I can't figure out how to define a correct projection for the data I am trying to replace.

Any comments will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML5</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=650, user-scalable=yes">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

  <style>

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #mapcanvas{

      height:100%;
    }

  </style>

  <script>


   var geoJsonObject;
   var thejson;

   $(document).ready(function(){



  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.284335, -120.833818),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map=new google.maps.Map($('#mapcanvas')[0], mapOptions);

//county.json is a topojson file

  $.getJSON("uscounty.json", function(data){
        geoJsonObject = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties)
        map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject); 
      }); 



  });//end document ready


 </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapcanvas">
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that your topojson is already projected. It contains coordinates already laid out in Cartesian coordinates. There is no spatial reference to your data, take a look at how Mike Bostock 'projects' it in [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4136647). He merely uses a null projection by not assigning one to the geoPath: `var path = d3.geoPath();`. You can also see that this is already projected data as the coordinate values (once converted to geojson) are not valid latitude longitude pairs: `[490.18252332008296,270.6981101474867]`

A null projection takes the coordinates in the geographic features it is fed and turns them into svg coordinates with no transform or translation. Essentially the topojson you have just has pixel values. You can't project it, it is already projected. You don't know its projection so you can't unproject it and re-project it to meet your needs. Nor do you know what projection it uses so that you could make google maps conform to your topojson.

I suggest finding a geojson of your area of interest that uses WGS84 (lat long pairs), rather than pixel coordinates that have already been projected. Then you can at least begin to match the projections between google maps and d3.

Comment: Thanks you Andrew! Your detailed answer helps me a lot. The topojson data I tried to use has projection just as you said. I noticed that there are transform and translate tags at the first several lines of the data. I guess that's how the data was projected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use topojson rather than geojson because geojson at county level makes the loading process really slow but topojson has a much smaller size.

For anyone else who has the same problem, I figure out two possible solutions based on information and tutorials people shared online: 
1) A topojson file of us counties with no projection(or a Albers Projection?): http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json (don't know why but it works great with the code I posted in the question)
2) Build a topojson by yourself from a shapefile: http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/06/converting-shapefiles-to-topojson.html